# How to represent a dictionary in Swift with nested types from JSON

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

Let's say I am parsing JSON and need to convert it to a Swift dictionary.  If you notice below, the type is fairly nested.  There's an accounts key with a value which is another map, with nested arrays and such.  I've seen many posts that suggest either AnyObject? or Any?  What's the correct way of doing this?  A full example would be great.  I'm using Alamofire / SwiftyJSON.  Thanks!

```
    {
        "id": "20o2k2jlkja08a08",
        "username": "catlover",
        "accounts": {
            "verified_email": "false",
            "identities": [{
                "network": "facebook",
                "token": "alkdjlaksjsak",
                "avatar": "avatarUrl"
            }, {
                "network": "twitter",
                "token": "alkdjlaksjsak",
                "avatar": "avatarUrl"
            }]
        },
        "followers": "100",
        "following": "20"
    }
```

Comment: Best way is to create a model class/struct that maps to that JSON and that can be initialized with a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you look at [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper#easy-mapping-of-nested-objects) and [AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper) frameworks, both available on Cocoapods. With them, mapping from JSON to Swift's object is really easy.

First, define how the JSON maps to your object:

```
import ObjectMapper

class User: Mappable {
    var id: String?
    var username: String?
    var accounts: UserAccount?
    var followers: Int?
    var following: Int?

    required init?(_ map: Map) { /* validate your JSON, etc */ }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.id         <- map["id"]
        self.username   <- map["username"]
        self.accounts   <- map["accounts"]
        self.followers  <- map["followers"]
        self.following  <- map["following"]
    }
}

class UserAccount: Mappable {
    var verifiedEmail: Bool?
    var identities: [UserIdentity]?

    required init?(_ map: Map) { }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.verifiedEmail  <- map["verified_email"]
        self.identities     <- map["identities"]
    }
}

class UserIdentity: Mappable {
    var network: String?
    var token: String?
    var avatar: NSURL?

    required init?(_ map: Map) { }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.network    <- map["network"]
        self.token      <- map["token"]
        self.avatar     <- (map["avatar"], URLTransform())
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
    .responseObject { (response: Response<User, NSError>) in
        let user = response.result.value

        // Get the url to the user's avatar
        let avatarURL = user?.accounts?.identities?.first?.avatar
    }
```

If you want to avoid all those `?`, simply give your properties a default value. Of course, this makes sense only if the property is guaranteed to be present in your JSON:

```
class User: Mappable {
    var id = ""
    var username = ""
    var accounts = UserAccount()
    var followers = 0
    var following = 0

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  What is the <- syntax called?

Comment: I guess you can call it "the mapping operator". It's not a standard Swift operator but a custom one defined by the `ObjectMapper` framework

Answer (score 0):

You have to mach the JSON document Array/Dictionary to your own classes structure. Something like this...

```
public class Identity
{
    public var network: String
    public var token: String
    public var avatarURI: NSURL
}

public class Account
{
    public var verifiedEmail: Bool
    public var identities: [Identity]
}

public class Profile
{
    public var profileID: String
    public var userName: String
    public var accounts: [Account]
    public var followers: Int
    public var following: Int
}
```